# Finding all pairs of two collections that match a predicate using functional style in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am currently learning Scala and I am looking for good ways to get the most out of functional programming style.

I am trying to do the following:

> Given two collections, I want to list every possible combination of two entries that match a predicate.

Now I could solve it using two loops and saving every result in a new collection, but is there a more elegant scala-ey solution?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide solutions that you have tried so far. The double loop one and maybe anything else you did in "functional" style.

Comment: Yeah, `flatMap` and `filter` should do the trick. You may even use **for comprehension** to make it more readable. Give it a shoot, and return back if you have any problems.

Comment: You can start with euler project or ninety nine problems and solutions. Here you can find more about them: https://pavelfatin.com/ninety-nine/, https://pavelfatin.com/scala-for-project-euler/

Answer (score 2):

You can start with

```
val col1: List[Int]
val col2: List[Int]

col1.map { i =>
  col2.map { j =>
    (i -> j)
  }.filter { case (i, j) =>
   // condition
  }
}.flatten
```

`map` and `flatten` should be the easiest to understand in the beginning. Play a bit with the idea to look a the types.

Then you might try to replace `map(f).flatten` with `flatMap(f)`:

```
col1.flatMap { i =>
  col2.map { j =>
    (i -> j)
  }.filter { case (i, j) =>
   // condition
  }
}
```

This is almost identical to this for comprehension:

```
for {
  i <- col1
  j <- col2
  ij = (i, j)
  if condition(ij)
} yield ij
```

which might be easier to read as

```
for {
  i <- col1
  j <- col2
  if condition(i, j)
} yield (i, j)
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/mhFZMjt/0